# Prevent Code from changing a disabled Button's text (VB)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

For a final project in school I am making a Tic Tac Toe game. The basic premise is on button click the buttons text goes to "X" and the button is disabled, then the buttons around it will randomly be selected to turn to an "O". (I am trying to make a fake AI to play with)

Ok so the problem is; even though the button is disabled on click, when you click on another button near it the text on another button can be disabled. For example if you press button A1 and the bot places an "O" on B2, and then you press on A2 and even though A1 is disabled with an "X" on it, the bot will change A1 to "O"

[Picture of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrOgT.png)

So how do you not allow the code to be able to change the text? 
Here's the code: [Pastebin Of code](http://pastebin.com/t9J53fJZ)

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself***.  See: [Ask].  Also, VB.Net IsNot vba

Comment: The desired behavior is on button click, the button will be disabled and make it so the button text can NOT be changed by anything; even if told to do so. Then the program will randomly place an "O" near it. I have the button disabled and a randomly placed box done on click but if you try this on another box it is able to manipulate the disabled buttons text. I have found this very difficult to explain and the picture above explains it better. Here is the shortened code [link](http://pastebin.com/mcpFBAyV)

Answer (score 0):

In your code there are bunch of similar `if` statement blocks where you test the variable `rnd` (the choice made by your bot) and then set the text of a button based on that value:

```
If rnd = 1 Then
    Button3.Text = "O"
    Button3.Enabled = False
End If
If rnd = 2 Then
    Button6.Text = "O"
    Button6.Enabled = False
End If
If rnd = 3 Then
    Button5.Text = "O"
    Button5.Enabled = False
End If
```

If you add an `And` condition that tests if that button is `Enabled` or not, then you should have a fix for what you asked in the question.

Try it like this instead:

```
If rnd = 1 And Button3.Enabled Then
    Button3.Text = "O"
    Button3.Enabled = False
End If
If rnd = 2 And Button6.Enabled Then
    Button6.Text = "O"
    Button6.Enabled = False
End If
If rnd = 3 And Button5.Enabled Then
    Button5.Text = "O"
    Button5.Enabled = False
End If
```

and so on, for the various groups of `if` statements like these one that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
//assign bool for 9 buttons

Dim btnOne as bool
Dim btnTwo as bool

Dim aiIsDone as bool;

aiIsDone = false;
//and so on..


Do While (aiIsDone == false) //Loop until it finds an unoccupied value

//assign random numbers
Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((9 * Rnd()) + 1))

if (value == 1) then

    if(btnOne == false) then //Check the random result if it is not occupied yet
    // Some code
    btnOne = true //turn the button to occupied so it will not pick the same button again
    aiIsDone = True //this will exit the loop

// continue statement for 9 buttons

end if

Loop

//Do something if all 9 are occupied (value is true)
```

Comment: So when 'AiIsDone' = true, the player is able to click on a button which in return makes that button = false? Also where in this code would I put the buttonx.text =  "O"?

Comment: aiIsDone = True this is only the condition to exit the loop.

Comment: just put it under the condition if(btnOne == false)

Comment: if it is the AI change the text to buttonx.text = "O" else "X"

Comment: The double equals in the If statements gives a "Expression detected" error. Do you also want me to change the 'bool' to Boolean or generate a class for bool? Can you annotate and or elaborate on the code so a novice like me could understand it better? Sorry for the troubles.